# Can I create a freeze pane and a split pane in the same sheet at once using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf, hssf

I am using Apache POI XSSF and HSSF API.

If I do this, it only freezes the pane (no split):

```
sheet1.createSplitPane(8000, 5000, 0, 0, Sheet.PANE_LOWER_RIGHT);
sheet1.createFreezePane(0, 1);
```

and if I do this, it only splits the pane (no freeze):

```
sheet1.createFreezePane(0, 1); 
sheet1.createSplitPane(8000, 5000, 0, 0, Sheet.PANE_LOWER_RIGHT);
```

How should I make both work together in the same sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Excel doesn't support having both a freeze pane and a split pane in the same sheet.  [This link](http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=211803) appears to indicate that Excel doesn't allow it.

Regardless of whether Excel does/will allow it, POI doesn't support it either.

The Javadocs for [createSplitPane](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#createSplitPane%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) explicitly state:

> Creates a split pane. Any existing freezepane or split pane is overwritten.

and the Javadocs for [createFreezePane](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#createFreezePane%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) say something similar.

> Creates a split (freezepane). Any existing freezepane or split pane is overwritten.

Also, just opening up Excel (I have Excel 2010), if I create a split pane, then a freeze pane, the split pane disappears.  If I then create a split pane, then the freeze pane disappears.

Excel (at least through 2010) doesn't appear to support both a freeze pane and a split pane simultaneously, and Apache POI respects that fact.